# Passing custom objects from VBA to VBScript

Tags: vba, object, vbscript, excel

I have a function in an Excel file that returns a custom class, when i try to call this function from VBScript i get an "Unknown runtime error"

Sample VBA Code:

```
Function myVBAFunc() As Variant
   Set myClass1 = New Class1
   myClass1.Name = "Test"
   Set myVBAFunc= myClass1
End Function
```

Calling VBScript code:

```
Set Excel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
Set Workbook = Excel.Workbooks.open("C:\myFile.xls")
Set myRes = Excel.Run("myVBAFunc")
Excel.Quit
```

I am getting an error when i try to set myRes, I assume this is caused by VBScript not recognizing the object's type. Is there any way to work around this?

Thanks,
Achraf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the instancing property of the class module (in its property window) from *Private* to *PublicNotCreatable*.

(You can also strictly type the function)

```
Function myVBAFunc() As Class1
   Set myVBAFunc= New Class1
   myVBAFunc.Name = "Test"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, that's much better now, I can access the object and use it. However as soon as the Excel object is closed i can no longer use the object! Is there anyway to copy the object locally to VBS so i can use it without keeping Excel open? thx

Comment: I doubt very much you can do that at all, if you don't need excels functionality at all give the class a method of returning whatever data you need from it and use it in vbs